# Firefox Animation Stuttering

Tags: jquery, css, firefox, jquery-isotope

I'm using jquery-isotope which uses 'best available' from css3 or jquery to animate.
But in **Firefox** there is a lot of stuttering in the animations.
Also on hovering something weird appears with the text.
http://isiddharth.com/beta/index.html#skills 
**Open in Firefox**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjdAV.png  -- Screenshot

In the **1st image of 2nd line** , there is something weird above the 'Mechanics'

Can the problem be related to graphics capabilities of the user's machine?

Comment: I took a look at your link with FF21.0 - everything seems to work well. Nice page, BTW. Can you post a simple example that demonstrates the problem, or give a clear pointer to where the problem occurs?

Comment: thanks Mike. Is animation rendering dependent upon the hardware specs of the machine. I mean do browser animations utilize the local GPU?

Comment: Sorry Sid - I still don't see a problem on my machine (an elderly, single core CPU at 2.4GHz). There is an occasional stutter, but I put that down to the usual vagaries of Javascript. Firefox has always had a problem with smoothness of animations due to it's garbage collect system, but it's much improved since Progressive GC was introduced. Animation performance is related to machine performance, and using the GPU is possibly an option for the browser implementors where you're using CSS. I couldn't say whether they use it or not.

Comment: Why are you repeating the same question? Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076352/firefox-transition-rendering-is-buggy and and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17077059/firefox-jquery-animation-stuttering

Answer (score 1):

Firefox has a very poor animation engine.  It always rounds things to an even pixel instead of supporting sub-pixel rendering, and it does the animation either in the same thread that it does a lot of other things on, or it blocks the animation thread quite often.  Unfortunately, it makes for very unsmooth animations with lots of stuttering.  It's the browser, not a lot you can do about it.  If people want to continue to use that browser despite it's poor animation, there really isn't much you can do about it.